# What is the Physics SE logo supposed to be?

Tags: discussion, design, site-enhancement

What is the favicon of the site supposed to represent? My initial impressions are that it looks like a partially unrolled condom. I'm not trying to be a troll, but I just don't see it making a good first impression. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 16):

I believe that it is intended to be [the so-called *"Mexican hat"* potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking#Mathematical_example%3a_the_Mexican_hat_potential) that plays an important role in [Goldstone style spontaneous symmetry breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson).

Comment: Indeed that is the case.

Comment: [Interactive 3D version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVyrEOQDAQANBfudTSJke0GAzd8AVmIpyQlJO2xOeLNz9PD7s77nyOl-NYLFK-g0m1GgyCfDFHnZlKIczs2FuRFE3d1K1A-Pt48X7GYMsc4aCw2d7fhLD66SDbTS6Q-gDWMB6G&lang=sage) of the logo.